# R excluding outliers in statistical data

Tags: r, outliers

I have data for bird species where I am comparing wing length and weight over years and over each other. I noticed that some of the data received from ringing stations included inaccurate inputs. An example is for a certain specie, the wing length was everything between 40-60mm however, there is an outlier at 578mm and this must be a result of input error. Is it possible to exclude these extreme outliers from the data set?

Comment: Please, provide your dataset or a dummy example. you can do this using ```dput(your_data_frame)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove these values from your dataframe with something like

```
df <- df[-which(df$wing_length > 500), ]
```

An example:

```
> df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b=11:20)
> df
    a  b
1   1 11
2   2 12
  ...
9   9 19
10 10 20
> df <- df[ - which(df$a>5), ]
> df
  a  b
1 1 11
2 2 12
3 3 13
4 4 14
5 5 15
```

Comment: I think the negative sign should be outside the `which` statement.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options:

1. Remove the outliers entirely.

```
max_believable_value=100
mydata = mydata[ mydata>max_believable_value ]
```

This isn't generally very satisfying, firstly because it removes them 'invisibly', so you don't notice if something more serious is systematically happening, and secondly because it changes the form of your data.  If you have 100 samples, and one observation for a particular sample is considered an 'outlier' but the others are Ok, perhaps you don't want to completely remove the entire sample.

2. Mark the outliers as 'NA'.

```
mydata[ mydata>max_believable_value ] = NA
```

This is exactly what the 'NA' values is intended to signify (a 'Not Available' value), and most R functions contain options that allow you to specify how to handle NA values (including by removing them!).
This approach leaves it clear how many 'outliers' (or other fishy values) you have, and also allows you to keep samples in your data even if one or more observations appear non-valid.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can filter your data using

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, wing_length < 500)
```

Sometimes the real deal is in choosing what number to use as the limit to exclude outliers. Some people use 3x the data's standard deviation:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- filter(df, wing_length < (sd(df$wave_length)*3))
```